# Remove Substring from the Original String

Tags: java, string, substring

I am attempting to remove a substring from the original string

code attempted:

```
String details = events.event_details.value[bi];
String details2 ="";
if(details.length()>70) {
    details2 = details.substring(70);
    details.replaceFirst(details2, " ");
}
```

Comment: Note that a `String` is immutable, `details.replaceFirst(details2, " ")` won't alter `details` at all .

Comment: So you want to take a string, if it's longer than 70 characters, change the first 70 characters to spaces?

Comment: Hi @lgrimes12 welcome to SO. I recommend to post an actual question in future, as I don't see any question mark. Also please provide some context on what you need to accomplish, e.g. do you need to return the modified string? Do you need to replace with a space or remove? And so on. Please have a look around the site to get a feeling of good questions&answers.

Comment: @Niccolò good *questions

Answer (score 0):

You do not remove it, you overwrite it with spaces...
remove is: cut it off!
replace: replace it!

```
details2 = details.substring(61, 70);
```

this gives you 10 chars

```
details2 = details.substring(details.length-10, details.length);
```

last 10

if you want 60 spaces and then the last 10, you need to create a String with 60 spaces, and use above method to extract whatever you want

maybe use a StringBuffer for this...

```
StringBuffer strg = new StringBuffer();
String cut = details.substring(details.length-10, details.length);
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i++).limit(60).forEach((a) -> strg.append(" "));
strg.append(cut);
System.out.println(strg.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your result from replaceFirst(...) somewhere,
as example again in details:

```
details = details.replaceFirst(details2, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way-

```
    String details2 ="";
    String result = ""

    if(details.length()>70) {
        details2 = details.substring(70);
        result = details.replaceFirst(details2, " ");
    }

System.out.println(result);
```

Here need a `String` variable where contain that replace's result